# HTML Select Box show as Multiple, but to Disable Multiple Selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, multiple-select

I needed to have:

- A html `<select>` box showing as a vertically expanded box (not a Dropdown). So i set it as `multiple`.

Then it is showing correctly as:

```
<select id="gagaga" multiple>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

How can i make it non-multiple selectable (to allow only 1 selection)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use this  `size="3"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="gagaga" size="3">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

If the value of the size attribute is greater than 1, but lower than the total number of options in the list, the browser will add a scroll bar to indicate that there are more options to view.

Comment: great but missed the `multiple`.

Comment: Multiple is not required. OP want only one option to be selected

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the multiple attribute instead set the size for it .

Quoted from w3schools:

> The size attribute specifies the number of visible options in a
>   drop-down list.
>
> If the value of the size attribute is greater than 1, but lower than
>   the total number of options in the list, the browser will add a scroll
>   bar to indicate that there are more options to view.

Comment: what about multiple selection?

Comment: "Then how can i make it non-multiple selectable? (to allow only 1 selection)" ,If i am not wrong ,  he is asking for single selection

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide `size` to it:

```
<select id="gagaga" size='3'>
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
</select>
```

and just remove the `multiple` there, It will enable you to select just one option in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="gagaga" size="3">
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you put multiple then user can select multiple items from the list.